# Background repeating, html won't lengthen

Tags: html, css, ruby, sinatra

```css
body {
  font-family: "Bubblegum Sans", cursive;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #b15c3a, #bf7549, #cd8d5b, #daa66f, #e7be86, #e6c38d, #e5c894, #e4cd9b, #d4c092, #c5b489, #b6a781, #a79b78);
  margin: auto;
}
h1 {
  font-family: "Bubblegum Sans", cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  color: black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-family: "Bubblegum Sans", cursive;
  background-color: #b4c5b2;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
button:hover {
    background-color: #CC7C5D;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #CC7C5D
}
label {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
button {
  font-family: "Bubblegum Sans", cursive;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  background-color: #b4c5b2;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777
}
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    justify-items: center;
    
}

img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
header {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.arrival img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.top5 img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.front_image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    top: -20px;
}
h1 {
    color: aliceblue;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000, -1px 1px 0 #000, 1px 1px 0 #000;
}

.logo {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
h2 {
    border: black 1px solid;
    background-color: #F9DEA7;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
#one {
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
#two {
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
#three {
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
img {
    border: black 3px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 6px -6px #777;
}
.logo {
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    box-shadow: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) { 
    html {
        width: fit-content;
    }
```

```html
    <img src="https://scontent-syd2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/274113850_673364380485459_1077356973253538626_n.png?_nc_cat=105&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=ae9488&_nc_ohc=AizJdQKc83wAX-MumBI&tn=9KISyor-vOFY9gGd&_nc_ht=scontent-syd2-1.xx&oh=03_AVLt0G0RnMan3KnJ_bY8724dlW2SQO__Jk1iNpmgiLcjDg&oe=623B9C68" alt="" class="logo">


<% if logged_in? %>
    <h2>Welcome back</h2>

    <header class="header">    
        <a href="/add_records" class="add_records">Add to your collection</a> 

        <a href="/edit_top_five" class="edit_top5">Edit Top 5</a>

        <a href="/edit_collection" class="edit_collection">Edit Collection</a>

        <a href="/edit_arrival" class="edit_arrival">Edit no.1 Monthly Arrival</a></header>

        <form action="/sessions" method= "POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">

            <button class = "logout">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </header>
    <h2>My no.1 Arrival This Month</h2>
    <div class="container" id="one">
        
        <% arrival.each do |no1| %>
            <div class="arrival">
                <p><%= no1['artist_name'] %> </p> <img src="<%= no1['img_url'] %>" alt="">
                <p><%= no1['album_name'] %></p>
                

                <form action="/delete_from_arrival" method="POST">

                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= no1['id'] %>">
            
                    <button>X</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        <% end %>
        
    </div> 

    <h2>My Top 5</h2>
    <div class="container" id="two">           
        <% top_5.each do |fav| %>
            <div class="top5">
                <p> <%= fav['artist_name'] %> </p><img src="<%= fav['img_url'] %>" alt=""><p><%= fav['album_name'] %></p>
                
            
                <form action="remove_from_top_5" method="POST">

                    <input type="hidden" name="fav_id" value="<%= fav['id'] %>">

                    <button>X</button>

                </form>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <h2>My Collection</h2>
    <div class="container" id="three">
        
        <% records.each do |vinyl| %>
            <div class="collection" id="three">        
                <p><%= vinyl['artist_name']  %> </p>
                <img src="<%= vinyl['img_url'] %>" alt="">
                <p><%= vinyl['album_name'] %></p>
            </div> 
        <% end %>
    </div>      
      
<% else %>

    <header>
        <a href="/users/sign_up">Sign Up</a>
        <a href="/login">Log In</a>
    </header>
<% end %>
```

[image: Current Home page]

This is my current home page. The HTML ends just under the signup and login buttons. Because of my gradient background I've just noticed this. How can I lengthen or just remove the two repeats of the background?

I've uploaded the code as and edit.
The other pages once logged in seem ok just the login page is having this issue, I'm guessing because there is more content on the other pages.

Comment: Pls add your HTML and CSS code so that we can help you

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue with the code you have provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED according to the updated question**

This depends on how you structured your HTML, ideally you should have background given for your document  element:

Practically all you need to add is

```css
html{
  height:100%;
}
```

Your solution in your CSS:

```css
html{
  height:100%;
}

body{
  min-height:100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #b15c3a, #bf7549, #cd8d5b, #daa66f, #e7be86, #e6c38d, #e5c894, #e4cd9b, #d4c092, #c5b489, #b6a781, #a79b78);
}
```

Comment: `height: 100%;` means 100% height of the parent. `html` has no parent and is always calculated to fit-content. `body` has a parent but also is calculated to fit-content and wont do anythign with 100%. What you proberly mean is `body { min-height: 100vh; }`. Not a min-height as you otherwise possibly causing overflow issues.